# How to display the title of the node in plain text in TWIG on Drupal 8?

Tags: tags, twig, drupal-8, markup

I created TWIG for my node, my products, my groups and my stores.

I'm on Drupal 8. For my nodes, I want to display the title. I use the following code:

```
{{ label }}
```

But there is the markup inside and I do not want it. So I tried the following code and it works. But is it a good practice ?

```
{{ label.0 }}
```

How to display the title of the node in plain text in TWIG on Drupal 8 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using the `node.html.twig` or a child of that template, you will have access to the `node` variable, which is a limited implementation of the `node` object.

From the comments for the classy theme `node.html.twig` file:

```
 * - node: The node entity with limited access to object properties and methods.
 *   Only method names starting with "get", "has", or "is" and a few common
 *   methods such as "id", "label", and "bundle" are available. For example:
 *   - node.getCreatedTime() will return the node creation timestamp.
 *   - node.hasField('field_example') returns TRUE if the node bundle includes
 *     field_example. (This does not indicate the presence of a value in this
 *     field.)
 *   - node.isPublished() will return whether the node is published or not.
```

As is described in that comment, the value of the node title without any markup can be accessed in twig by using:

`{{ node.label }}`.